# Calling Promise.all() executes correctly but calling await on individual promises does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have some code that iterates over a list of objects representing files. In the loop there is a call to 'getRequest()' which returns type 'Promise<Response>' and then a call to '.text()' which returns 'Promise<string>'. I have a working solution that first gets all the promises into a list and then calls Promise.all() and the documents are fetched correctly.

**However when I try another solution where I am directly waiting for the promise to return and then using the values, the documents are not populated correctly.**

```
//----------------------------- WORKING SOLUTION ---------------------------------------
async function parseDocumentation(config: Map<string, ConfigElement[]>) {
    const promises: Promise<Response>[] = [];
    const documents: Documentation[] = [];

    config.forEach((sectionDef: ConfigElement[]) => {
        sectionDef.forEach(entry => {
            if (!entry.subsection) {
                // getRequest: (endpointUrl: string) => Promise<Response>
                promises.push(getRequest(entry.source));
            }
        });
    });
    try {
        await Promise.all(promises).then(async responses => {
            for (const response of responses) {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject();
                } else {
                    const document = {source: '', markDown: '' };
                    document.markDown = await entry.text(); // Body.text(): Promise<string>
                    document.source = response.url;
                    documents.push(document);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        Dialog.error('Failed to load page.', e);
    }
}

//----------------------------- NON WORKING SOLUTION ---------------------------------------
async function parseDocumentation(config: Map<string, ConfigElement[]>) {
    const documents: Documentation[] = [];

    config.forEach((sectionDef: ConfigElement[], sectionName: string) => {
        sectionDef.forEach(async entry => {
            if (!entry.subsection) {
                entry.hash = 'some_hash_value_' + sectionName;
                await getRequest(entry.source).then(async response => {
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        return Promise.reject();
                    } else {
                        const document = {source: '', markDown: '' };
                        await response.text().then(async text => {
                            // would like to save entry.hash to document here
                            document.markDown = text;
                            document.source = response.url;
                            documents.push(document);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Can anyone explain what is happening? I think I mirrored the logic correctly but for some reason the second variation does not populate documents correctly.

Comment: It's a really good idea to strictly avoid mixing `async/await` Promise handling and `.then()` Promise handling. Use one or the other.

Comment: Your `await`s work. You just never wait for `forEach`, because it's impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `.forEach(async ....` construct: the callback is an asynchronous function, and the first `await` in it will return/suspend *that* callback function (not the outer function), making the `forEach` loop continue with the next iterations. The asynchronous code (below `await`) in the callbacks will only execute when the callstack is empty, so the `forEach` will already have finished its iterations before that happens.

To solve this, use a loop construct that doesn't need a callback, like `for..of`. Then the `await`s operate on the `parseDocumentation` function itself:

```
async function parseDocumentation(config: Map<string, ConfigElement[]>) {
    const documents: Documentation[] = [];

    for (const [sectionName: string, sectionDef: ConfigElement[]] of config) {
        for (const entry: ConfigElement of sectionDef) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Not the question, but try to get the most out of `await` by getting the promised value from it -- avoiding a `then` chain:

```
async function parseDocumentation(config: Map<string, ConfigElement[]>) {
    const documents: Documentation[] = [];

    for (const [sectionName: string, sectionDef: ConfigElement[]] of config) {
        for (const entry: ConfigElement of sectionDef) {
            if (entry.subsection) continue;
            entry.hash = 'some_hash_value_' + sectionName;
            const response = await getRequest(entry.source);
            if (!response.ok) throw new Error("One of the responses was not OK");
            documents.push({
                source: response.url,
                markDown: await response.text(),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that throwing an error in an `async` function will reject the function's returned promise with as reason the error message.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! i figured it out with the comments but this solution was nice to see too

Answer (score -1):

You should do :

`let text = await response.text();`